# array_multisort - Does not sort my complete table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am trying to use the array_multisort function for my first time but it is not working as I expected it. I really hope that someone can help me out. Here is my problem:

I do have a table with 7 columns. I want to sort 4 of them by clicking on the name of the column. My Problem is that the sorting process always works only for one column. Let me explain you what I mean. Here are my 4 columns I want to sort:

```
Points | Name | Leader | Owner
10 | Chris | Thomas | Philip
0 | Alex | Sandy | Oscar
5 | David | Lucas | Kathi
```

Now with my code when I click on the "Name" for example than my table will be sorted like this:

```
Points | Name | Leader | Owner
10 | Alex | Thomas | Philip
0 | Chris | Sandy | Oscar
5 | David | Lucas | Kathi
```

When I click on "Owner" for example my table looks like this:

```
Points | Name | Leader | Owner
10 | Chris | Thomas | Kathi
0 | Alex | Sandy | Oscar
5 | David | Lucas | Philip
```

So as you can see, only the column that I have clicked will be sorted alphabetically and not the entire table. That is not what I need.

The whole table should be sorted so as an example it should look like this. When I click on "Leader" the complete table should be sorted like this:

```
Points | Name | Leader | Owner
5 | David | Lucas | Kathi
0 | Alex | Sandy | Oscar
10 | Chris | Thomas | Philip
```

Here is my code.
Notice: Everything is working fine, it is just a part of my complete code but I hope that someone can tell me what exactly I am doing wrong and what my code should look like so that the complete table will be sorted.

```
<form name='form1' action='./index.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='func' value='".$func."'>
<input type='hidden' name='submenu' value='".$submenu."'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."'>
<input type='hidden' name='module_id' value='".$module_id."'>
<input type='hidden' name='save_data' value='true'>
<input type='hidden' name='sort' value='".$sort."'>
<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='".$sid."'>

<br><table>
<tr>
<td>P</td>
<td>L</td>
<td>E</td>
<td>O</td>
<td><a href='./index.php?func=$func&submenu=$submenu&id=$id&module_id=$module_id&sort=attendance_points&sid=$sid'>Points</a></td>
<td><a href='./index.php?func=$func&submenu=$submenu&id=$id&module_id=$module_id&sort=student_name&sid=$sid'>Student</a></td>
<td><a href='./index.php?func=$func&submenu=$submenu&id=$id&module_id=$module_id&sort=leader_name&sid=$sid'>Leader</a> | <a href='./index.php?func=$func&submenu=$submenu&id=$id&module_id=$module_id&sort=owner_name&sid=$sid'>Owner</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
$output=array();

if ($sort=="") { $sort="student_name"; }
array_multisort($output[$sort], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);

for ($x=0;$x<count($output["id"]);$x++) {
    $attendance=getUserModuleAttendanceInfo($output["pers_id"][$x],$id,$module_id);

        print "<tr>";
            if (count($attendance["id"])==0) {
                print "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='part_1_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' value='1'></td>";
                print "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='part_2_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' value='1'></td>";
                print "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='part_3_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' value='1'></td>";
                print "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='part_4_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' value='1'></td>";

                if($output["edit_coursepoints"][$x]==0) {
                    print "<td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='points_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' id='spinner_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' value='".$module["points_present"][0]."'></td>";
                }
                else {
                     print "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='points_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' id='spinner_".$output["pers_id"][$x]."' value='".$module["points_present"][0]."'></td>";
                }
                $controller_list.="spinner_".$output["pers_id"][$x].";";
            } else {
                print "<td colspan='4' valign='center' align='center'><span class='label label-".$course_part_state["style"][$attendance["part_state"][0]]."'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-".$course_part_state["icon"][$attendance["part_state"][0]]." bigger-120'></i> ".strtoupper($course_part_state["txt"][$attendance["part_state"][0]])."</span></td>";
                print "<td align='center'>".$attendance["part_points"][0]."</td>";
            }


            print "<td>".$staffshort[$student["grade"][0]]." ".$output["student_name"][$x]."</td>";
            print "<td>leader: ".$staffshort[$leader["grade"][0]]." ".$output["leader_name"][$x]."<br>owner: ".$staffshort[$owner["grade"][0]]." ".$output["owner_name"][$x]."</td>";
            if (count($attendance["id"])>0) {
                print "<td align='center'><a href='./index.php?func=$func&submenu=$submenu&id=$id&module_id=$module_id&sort=$sort&undo=".$attendance["id"][0]."&sid=$sid'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-undo dark bigger-180'></i></a></td>";
            }
        print "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: thanks @Rocket Hazmat for formatting my table code! Didn´t know how to do that.

Comment: I just formatted it the same as the code blocks :-)

Comment: ah okay thank you! Do you also have an idea or a solution for my problem? :)

Comment: How is your `$output` array laid out?  Is each row in `$output` a table row?  Or do you have separate arrays for each field?

Comment: I edited my first post and entered my code for the $output array. Hope that helps! Your usort code was not working! Sorted the same as array_multisort

Comment: I would *highly* suggest reorganizing your `$output` array.  Instead of making each field into its own array, I'd suggest making `$output` an array of table rows, with key/values pairs.  Something like `$output[] = array('id' => $data["id"][$x], ...)`.  Then the sort code you have may work.

Comment: Is there no way to make the array_multisort working with my current $output? Are you sure? I really do not know what my $output array should look like when I reorganize it. :(

Comment: You *can* sort it the way you have, but it'll be a lot more work.  It'll be *much* easier to reorganize your `$output`.

Comment: Can you show me exactly what I need to change so that the sort function works with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reorganizing your `$output`.  Right now, you have an individual array for *each* field.  That's hard to work with.

It'll be easier if you have each row in `$output` be a table row with its own key/value pair.

So, try to build it like this:

```
$output[] = array(
    "id" => $data["id"][$x],
    "pers_id" => $student["pers_id"][0],
    "student_name" => $student["firstname"][0]." ".strtoupper($student["lastname"][0]),
    "owner" => $owner["pers_id"][0],
    "owner_name" => $owner["firstname"][0]." ".strtoupper($owner["lastname"][0]),
    "leader" => $leader["pers_id"][0],
    "leader_name" => $leader["firstname"][0]." ".strtoupper($leader["lastname"][0]),
    "edit_coursepoints" => $editcoursepoints,
    "attendance_points" => $attendance["part_points"][0]
);
```

Then you can sort this using `usort`:

```
usort($output, function($a, $b) use($sort){
    return strcmp($a[$sort], $b[$sort]);
});
```

Then when you build your table, you just loop over each row in `$output` and print out the values.

```
foreach($output as $row){
    echo '<tr>';

    echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='part_1_".$row["pers_id"]."' value='1'></td>";

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working like a charm! I really appreciate your help.